# Initialize a Custom SKSpriteNode with its properties from the editor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I made my own simple custom class called SKGlowNode as a subclass of SKSpriteNode. I originally wanted to be able to create a custom class and input all the init parameters in the editor like you can with a SKSpriteNode. However, I found out that this is not possible yet and I had to try to do it with user data. I set up my node in the editor like this:

[image]

And simply did the custom class like this:

[image]

Here is my class for SKGlowNode

```
import Foundation

import SpriteKit

class SKGlowNode: SKSpriteNode{

let colors = [UIColor.blue,UIColor.green,UIColor.red,UIColor.orange,UIColor.purple,UIColor.yellow,UIColor.white,UIColor.magenta]

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(texture: texture, color: .black, size: size)//error here

    let glowIndex = self.userData?.value(forKey: "glowColorIndex") as? Int ?? 0
    let glowTexture = self.userData?.value(forKey: "glowTexture") as? String ?? "squareBg"
    addGlow(radius: 75, texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: glowTexture), color: colors[glowIndex])
    //This glow function works and is an extension from a SKSpriteNode where it creates a glow from a texture with certain color

   }

}
```

Obviously I get an error on the line specified because I cant initialize the superclass using those variables, but I have no idea what to put in order to get it to initialize with the values already defined in the editor as it would work if there was no custom class. Thanks

Comment: try using super.init(coder: aDecoder) instead of your super.init

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: awesome! good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the appropriate Super.init for your class init.

If you are instantiating the subclassed SKSpriteNode in an init() whether it be the default or a custom init with custom parameters you use

```
super.init(texture: SKTexture, color: SKColor, size: CGSize)
```

if you are instantiating it from an sks scene file then required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) gets called and you need to have

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```